# How to get only rows with max version_id without expensive subquery in postgres database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-9.6

I have a data table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.data
(
    data_id bigint,
    date timestamp without time zone,
    value double precision,
    sensor_id integer,
    version_id integer
)
```

Now I need a query with good performance that retrieves all data rows with the highest version_id per sensor_id and date.

In other words, this rows:

```
date='2018-08-24 10:31';value=1337;sensor_id=1;version_id=1;
date='2018-08-24 10:31';value=4;sensor_id=1;version_id=2;
date='2018-08-24 10:32';value=45;sensor_id=1;version_id=1;
```

should lead with the query to this resulting data rows:

```
date='2018-08-24 10:31';value=4;sensor_id=1;version_id=2;
date='2018-08-24 10:32';value=45;sensor_id=1;version_id=1;
```

So all rows for that there is a newer version should be ignored.

The problem is, that I need a really good performance for it, cause the data table can contain e.g. 2.000.000.000 rows (they are in background partitionized - not relevant for my question I guess).

The simple solution for my problem is to check for each row in a subquery if it is the row with highest version_number:

```
SELECT * FROM data d1
WHERE d1.version_id= (
    SELECT MAX(d2.version_id) FROM data d2
    WHERE d2.sensor_id = d1.sensor_id AND d2.date = d2.date
);
```

This is very slow. By the way: I have the following unique index and b-tree indexes for this table:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX data_unique_index
    ON public.data USING btree
    (sensor_id, date, version_Id);

CREATE INDEX data_version_id_idx
    ON public.data USING btree
    (version_id);

CREATE INDEX data_date_idx
    ON public.data USING btree
    (date);

CREATE INDEX data_sensor_id_idx
    ON public.data USING btree
    (sensor_id);

CREATE INDEX data_date_sensor_id_idx
    ON public.data USING btree
    (date, sensor_id);
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: the index `data_date_idx` is useless and can be removed because you have another index with `date` as the leading column.

Comment: BTW: instead of `MAX(...)` you could use `NOT EXISTS(...)` this is very similar to the `row_number()` (or `RANK()`) method.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you, its good to know, I will remove the index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) (where n = 1) queries are usually best done using `distinct on ()`:

```
SELECT distinct on (sensor_id, date) * 
FROM data
order by sensor_id, date, version_id DESC;
```

Comment: thank you very much, this is the solution with a good performance and it works

Answer (score 2):

The `DISTINCT ON` answer by the @a_horse is the way to go if you really want just a single record from each date and session.  But, assuming there might be ties, you could a rank analytic function here:

```
SELECT data_id, date, value, sensor_id, version_id
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sensor_id, date ORDER BY version_id DESC) rank
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE rank = 1;
```

Comment: thanks for other possibilities. Indeed I really want just a single record for each date and sensor.